# Spring Refactor common controller redirection codes

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, spring-boot

I have some redirection codes in my Controller classes that I want to refactor.
These codes just check if an object is null, and if it is... it would redirect it to a particular page.

Below are parts of the code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/user-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userDetails(@RequestParam("id") int id) {

    ...

    User user = userService.getUserById(id);
    if (matter == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users-list.html");
    }

    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user-application-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userApplicationDetails(@RequestParam("applicationId") int applicationId) {

    ...

    UserApplication application = userApplicationService.getApplicationById(applicationId);
    if (application == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users-list.html");
    }

    ...
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user-activity-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView userActivityDetails(@RequestParam("activityId") int activityId) {

    ...

    UserActivity activity = userActivityService.getActivityById(activityId);
    if (activity == null) {
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/users-list.html");
    }

    ...
}
```

I would like to refactor the null checking and redirection to a separate class, but I am not sure how I could call it inside the controller and would do the redirection to the specified page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking whether a variable *is present* inside a controller is fine. You can improve on the syntax by using the Java 8 `Optional` API.

What you can do is move the *exception handling* to a separate class. Spring has a special component annotation exactly for this use case: `@ControllerAdvice` accompanied with `@ExceptionHandler` methods. This does require you to throw exceptions.

For an example, see:

```
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user-details", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView userDetails(@RequestParam("id") int id) {

        ...

        Optional<User> userOptional = userService.getUserById(id);
        User user = userOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException("message here"));

        ...
    }
}

@ControllerAdvice
public class SampleControllerAdvice {

    private static final String REDIRECT_USER_LIST = "redirect:/users-list.html";

    @ExceptionHandler
    public String handleUserNotFound(UserNotFoundException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        return REDIRECT_USER_LIST;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler
    public String handleUserActivityNotFound(UserActivityNotFoundException e, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("errorMessage", e.getMessage());
        return REDIRECT_USER_LIST;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. If the answer solved your question, please accept the answer to mark the question is solved. :)